# How to find similiarity of two vectors

Tags: python, scikit-learn, distance

I have 2 vectors

```
x = [18000,18000,1,8999.1913]
y = [18000,18000,1,9000.5]
```

I calculated Manhatten Distance between these two using Sklearn distance. I got value

```
1.3086
```

How to express this in percentage ?

Because by looking vectors, it seems both are almost same. So percentage value should come near 100%. How to achieve this.?

Comment: In percentage, with respect to what?

Comment: `1.3086` is `130.86%`. But that is totally unrelated to the Manhatt**a**n distance.

Comment: @coldspeed: I meant, How the score "1.3" tell that vectors are very closer.
For some other vectors the score may be "9.12" etc.
How to represent these scores to interpret similarity.

Comment: Your coordinates differ by 4 orders of magnitude. Manhattan distance in this situation is somewhat useless. Unless you _must_ use MD, use some other distance measure (e.g., correlation or cosine distance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this approach,

The Pearson correlation coefficient is probably the most widely used measure for linear relationships between two normally distributed variables as bellow,

[image]

where x and y are the two vectors and [image] are the meansof those vectors, value of r is always in between 0 and 1. Hence you may multipley 100 to get percentage value.

Here is the python implementation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html

```
>>> from scipy import stats
>>> x = [18000,18000,1,8999.1913]
>>> y = [18000,18000,1,9000.5]
>>> stats.pearsonr(x,y)
(0.99999999720381061, 2.7961893911410134e-09)
>>> r = stats.pearsonr(y,x)
>>> percentage = r[0]*100
>>> percentage
99.999999720381055
```